# Dynamically access variable names in R programming

Tags: r

I have a problem in R programming wherein I have to dynamically create  60 data frames dynamically which I am able to do using "assign" with the following code-

```
for(i in 1:60)
{
    assign(paste('shop', i, sep=""), as.data.frame(filter(dataset, shop_id == i)))
}
```

Where 'dataset' is the original data frame from which the subsets of 60 different data frames are now created. I now have to delete the 2 first columns from each of the 60 data frames created viz., 'date' and 'shop_id'.
For a static variable name, this could be done with for example with-

```
shop_id$date <- NULL
shop_id$shop_id <- NULL
```

But, how do I access the dynamically created variable name in a dynamic manner, say from within a 'for' loop?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should split the original data frame into a list according to `shop_id` and work from there. In other words I think this is one of those X~Y types of problems.

Comment: `shop<- list(); for (...) shop[[i]] <- ...` but you probably should read `help("split")` instead.